# How to configure Spring web-application starting directory?

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

I'm reading the  [Taming Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/books/taming-thymeleaf/) book and want to reproduce the [examples](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/taming-thymeleaf-sources) but using Gradle instead Maven (which used in original source code). Now I'm stalled with live auto reload configuration from chapter 4. Browsersync is working, but the source code changes does not to load to the browser.

In the original example Maven compiles classes to the just one `target` directory, from which the application then strarted by `Run As / Java Application` Eclipse's menu, as I can see in log (and auto reloading successfull work in this case):

```
2023-12-12 17:43:27.517  INFO 1269581 --- [           main] c.t.a.TamingThymeleafApplication         : Starting TamingThymeleafApplication using Java 17.0.6 on b586 with PID 1269581 (/home/sd/Deblauwe2022TamingThymeleafPractical/taming-thymeleaf-sources/chapter04/target/classes started by sd in /home/sd/Deblauwe2022TamingThymeleafPractical/taming-thymeleaf-sources/chapter04)
```

But when I use Gradle there are three build directories: `bin`, `build` and `target`. The first one - `bin` - I don’t know exactly for what. The second - `build` - is the standard gradle's build directory. And third - `target` directory - is the standard build Spring directory, if I'm not mistaken.

The my problem with auto reloading comes from the fact that the resources processes and copies to `target` directory (as it should be), but when I start application from IDE, the application starting from `bin` directory but not from the target:

```
2023-12-12T18:16:16.332+03:00  INFO 1281074 --- [           main] c.t.a.TamingThymeleafApplication         : Starting TamingThymeleafApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 1281074 (/home/sd/Deblauwe2022TamingThymeleafPractical/taming-thymeleaf/bin/main started by sd in /home/sd/Deblauwe2022TamingThymeleafPractical/taming-thymeleaf)
```

And if I start application by `gradle bootRun`, the application starting from `build` directory, not from the `target` directory again:

```
2023-12-12T18:30:56.932+03:00  INFO 1286252 --- [           main] c.t.a.TamingThymeleafApplication         : Starting TamingThymeleafApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 1286252 (/home/sd/Deblauwe2022TamingThymeleafPractical/taming-thymeleaf/build/classes/java/main started by sd in /home/sd/Deblauwe2022TamingThymeleafPractical/taming-thymeleaf)
```

So, I'm bit confised, because everything else works. How to start application from `target` directoy when using gradle, not maven?

Comment: You are mistaken. Gradle doesn't have a target directory (could be the intellij default). You shouldn't copy to the target directory but rather the build directory.

Comment: Is a target directory a Maven's default project layout directory, and a build directory is a Gradle's default project layour directory, and nothing else? So, to migrate live reload from Maven to Gradle I just need change copy from target directory to build directory. This makes more sense than my initial guess about the app's starting directory.

Comment: `build` is for Gradle, `target` is from Maven. I also believe Intellij uses a `target/out` or regular `out` sometimes. But for gradle you need the `build` directory.